# How do I manage HTTP communication between a Apache web server and Google App Engine?

Tags: java, php, mysql, http, google-app-engine

I am currently developing a web application in the Google App Engine using Java and PrimeFaces. I have to access a remote MySQL server, my clients website's database. This website contains all the data which my application requires.

I have searched the web and found out that there is no direct method to access any database with Google app engine.
So I decided to create a PHP script on the web server which will accept SQL queries as HTTP requests on behalf of the MySQL server and send the returned data as a HTTP response. (Encrypted of course!)
How can I send a large result set over HTTP from a PHP web server to Google App Engine?

The problem I am facing here is that, although I can manage to get a HTTP request via GET in PHP. How do I send them back, just flushing wont do, and how do I redirect them back to the Google App Engine's my application specifically.

Thanks!

Comment: Why "just flushing won't do"? Give us more details about your problem, along with what is it specifically that "won't do".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UrlFetch api to send requests from appengine to your MySQL server.  You'll get a response, and can parse it directly in appengine.

You can set up servlets in your appengine app that your MySQL server can trigger with requests.  Your MySQL server can send a request (your php GET function) to yourapp.appspot.com/servletpath, which will start your appengine servlet.  Appengine can return a response from there.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the reply.. Yeah I can do what I did with the PHP script write back here in Google App Engine too. THanks again for pointing me this out and the UrlFetch Api

Answer (score 0):

If dataset is too big to be transferred in one lump then just split it over several requests by adding a range limit to your query. Also make use of task queue to split this job over several tasks. It is common practice on appengine to split everything what takes too long/too big into several tasks. Divide and conquer.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more! How do you split your response into several responses in PHP. Is there any method or function to do this? I think this is a another question to be posted, it deserves it?

Comment: How do you add a range limit to your query? Do you mean the SQL LIMIT function?

Comment: Yes I mean that you should use LIMIT and do not request for too much data.

Comment: Thanks! But when you say 'too much data' how many KBs do you have in mind. Say, about 40000 Characters

Comment: urlfetch service has a limitation of 32 MB response-size and 10 minutes deadline so you need to keep it safe under these limitations.